# import is not defined erorr using es6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I try to follow a tutorial here. I have babel installed, but I couldn't detect what mistake I done below

sum.js

```
export default sum = (a, b) => {
    return a + b;
}
```

sum.test.js

```
import sum from './sum';

test('1 + 2 should equal to 3', () => {
    expect(sum(1,2)).toBe(3);
});
```

the error is sum is not defined in sum.test.js. 2 files are placed within the same level of directory.

Comment: You don't need to name the function, which could make this easier. `export default (a, b) => a + b;`

Answer (score 4):

I think, issue is you forgot to define `sum` in `sum.js`, Write it like this:

```
let sum;
export default sum = (a, b) => {
    return a + b;
}
```

or

```
let sum = (a, b) => {
    return a + b;
}

export default sum;
```

**Note**: In case of `default export` you can remove the name, because `default export` will be only one per file. At the time of importing you can use any name, like this:

`import ABC from './sum';`

**Update**:

There are two ways of defining a function:

```
1: function sum(){}
2: var sum = function(){}
```

So if you use first one then export it directly(no need of defining):

```
export default sum(){}
```

but if you use second one then you need to define the variable because you are storing the function definition in that variable:

```
let sum;

export default sum = () => {}
```

or

```
let sum = () => {}

export default sum;
```

Check this article: https://danmartensen.svbtle.com/build-better-apps-with-es6-modules

Comment: `export default sum = (a, b) => {}` I thought like this sum is the name of the function?

Comment: Your snippet is identical to `sum = (a, b) => {}; export default sum` meaning there is to `let` or `var`, so the `sum` variable is never declared.

Comment: why use `let` instead of `const` in this case?

Comment: In this case you can use const also, read the diff between these 3 let, car const.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to declare sum before using in export**

like var sum;